# Adding different segments in a loop ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make 4 plots with *n* different segments and points on each, for example, say I want to have **n=10**

```
library(gridExtra)
sim.beta=function(a,b,sig,n){
  x=runif(n,1,10)
  y=a+b*x+rnorm(n,0,sig)  
  return(data.frame(x,y))
}

a=10; b=5;sig=20;n=10

grafico=list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  s1=sim.beta(a,b,sig,n)
  X=s1$x;Y=s1$y
  z=qnorm(0.975)
  g=ggplot(s1,aes(x,y))+
    xlim(0,10)+
    ylim(a-z*sig,a+b*10+z*sig)
  g=g+geom_abline(intercept = a,slope = b,col=2)
  mod1=lm(s1$y~s1$x)
  for (j in 1:n) {
    r11=X[j];r21=a+b*r11
    g=g+ geom_segment(aes(x=r11,y=r21+z*sig,xend=r11,yend=r21-z*sig),linetype=2)
    g=g+geom_point(aes(x[j],y[j]),col=4)
  }
  g=g+geom_abline(aes(intercept=mod1$coefficients[1],slope=mod1$coefficients[2]),col=4,linetype=2)
  grafico[[i]]=ggplotGrob(g)
}

grid.arrange(grobs=grafico, ncol=2,nrow=2)
```

And this is what I get:
[image: plot]

Notice how I only get 1 segment and 1 point, but I want to have 10, like this with the plot function:

[image: plo2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into the fact that the mappings for layers are lazily evaluated. This means that the value of the variable used in the loop, is actually not evaluated until the plot is drawn, not at the time the layer is created. Use can use the `rlang` features to inject the current value into the layer. The part you need to change is here

```
  for (j in 1:n) {
    r11=X[j]; r21=a+b*r11
    g = g + geom_segment(aes(x=!!r11, y=!!r21+z*sig, xend=!!r11, yend=!!r21-z*sig), linetype=2)
    g = g + geom_point(aes(x[!!j], y[!!j]), col=4)
  }
```

Notice the addition of the `!!` before your loop variables. This captures their current values.